# Как получить значение jquery в выбранном блоке?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Ребят, всем привет. Есть такая верстка:

```
<div class="product_list">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="id"/>
<button class="add_cart">Добавить<span></span></button>
</div>

<div class="product_list">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="id"/>
<button class="add_cart">Добавить<span></span></button>
</div>

<div class="product_list">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="id"/>
<button class="add_cart">Добавить<span></span></button>
</div>
```

Когда нажимаю на "добавить", я хочу получить значение inputa name='id'. Как это реализовать из данной верстке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_cart', function() {
    var id = $(this).prev().val();
    alert(id);
});
```

или если вёрстка таки поменяется

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_cart', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.product_list').find('input[name="id"]').val();
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: мля это совсем не годиться, я же могу между inputami поставить некий html код. И он сразу перестанер работать!

Comment: @duddeniska, хм... Ты дал пример кода, на его основе мы и помогаем, ты же не написал что-то типа:  

    <input type='hidden' />
    /* Тут может быть код */
    <input type='button' />

Answer (score 1):

> jsfiddle.net/30dw5ncs/

Вот оптимальнее вариант, на родном JS

> jsfiddle.net/30dw5ncs/1/

```js
$('.add_cart').on('click', function(){
    var id = this.previousElementSibling.value;
    
    alert(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_list">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="id"/>
<button class="add_cart">Добавить<span></span></button>
</div>

<div class="product_list">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="id"/>
<button class="add_cart">Добавить<span></span></button>
</div>

<div class="product_list">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="id"/>
<button class="add_cart">Добавить<span></span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: тут правильнее использовать сиблингов, а не парента

Comment: @norbornen, я jQuery не пользуюсь, так что...

Comment: док почти работает, но только у меня выше написан select, и он никак не хочет брать его значения.

Comment: @TheDoctor, ты дал ответ на jquery и ты за ответ отвечаешь

Answer (score 0):

Решение строится на основе этих 2х вещей:

1. [Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
2. [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: @norbornen, вряд ли тот, кто задаёт такие вопросы, будет читать маны, да ещё на инглише.

Comment: и поэтому ты считаешь, что нужно, не объясняя, набросать на фидле любое решение? ну ок, чо

Comment: Нет, я люблю объяснять решение, но есть случаи, когда это вряд ли стоит делать.

Comment: не ребятЮ спасибо, я использую сейчас sublings Но есть небольшой гемор в том что в этом блоке есть в самом начале select, а намного ниже вот этот код, так вот input значения я получаю, те что рядом с кнопкой, а значение select не могу, вот и спрашиваю, может есть какие то другие решения?

Comment: @duddeniska, см. мой пример, там ищется код вне зависимости от его положения в родителе.

Comment: @duddeniska, я почти не понял набор слов в твоём комментарии про селект.

Имею сказать вот что - ты написал: html, вопрос и уточнение "Как это реализовать из данной верстке?", тебе даны ответы, работающие в данных условиях. И тут ты зачем-то начинаешь рассказывать про какой-то селект.

Удали вопрос, остановись, подумай, сформулируй заново.

Иначе это не вопрос, а какое-то гадание о том, что осталось за скобками.

Comment: @norbornen, в точку, бро!